# Firebase can't use a Gmail account as child

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

```
child("Members").child("billgate@gmail.com").setValue(people);
```

This my code that is crashing when I run it on my device, I'm trying to insert a Gmail account as a child in my Android Studio project but for some reason it keeps crashing but when I change it to a simple name it works:

```
child("Members").child("billgate").setValue(people);
```

but if I write it like this without including the @gmail.com part it works perfectly. However I need to set a Gmail account as my child.

Comment: check my answer hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use special characters in your firebase node names, you rather put the user ID instead of the email:

```
child("Members").child("userX").setValue(people);
```

or better with the unique ID of the user logged in.

```
child("Members").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(people);
```

Comment: Thanks Gaston it worked like a charm

Answer (score 1):

Because Firebase does not allow symbols as . in the key, I suggest you encode the email address like this:

> name@email.com -> name@email,com

As you probably see, instead of . I have used ,. To achieve this, you can use the following methods:

```
static String encodeUserEmail(String userEmail) {
    return userEmail.replace(".", ",");
}

static String decodeUserEmail(String userEmail) {
    return userEmail.replace(",", ".");
}
```